In ag-grid is there a way to stop the row drag using an external API call (e.g. because of a keyboard event)?
Is there a way in Ag-grid to stop the row drag while it's in motion?  I'd like to emulate Notion's behavior where if you're dragging and hit Escape it cancels the drag.  I've tried rowNode.setDragging(false) on the active RowNode being dragged but I don't think that's what tells the grid to stop dragging.
Looking deeper it looks like the gridBodyCtrl.getRowDragFeature uses a dragAndDropService - but it doesn't feel right to be mucking around in the internals of ag-grid that way.
